# GWT serialization exception

Tags: gwt, gwt-rpc

I have a simple service method which returns ArrayList. However when I call this method, I am getting an exception as follows:

```
com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.IncompatibleRemoteServiceException: The response could not be deserialized
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.RequestCallbackAdapter.onResponseReceived(RequestCallbackAdapter.java:221)
    at com.google.gwt.http.client.Request.fireOnResponseReceived(Request.java:287)
    at com.google.gwt.http.client.RequestBuilder$1.onReadyStateChange(RequestBuilder.java:395)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:167)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessagesWhileWaitingForReturn(BrowserChannelServer.java:326)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:207)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:132)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:561)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:269)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.apply(Impl.java)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.entry0(Impl.java:214)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:167)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessages(BrowserChannelServer.java:281)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:531)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:352)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.SerializationException: java.util.ArrayList/3821976829
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.SerializerBase.getTypeHandler(SerializerBase.java:153)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.SerializerBase.instantiate(SerializerBase.java:114)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.ClientSerializationStreamReader.deserialize(ClientSerializationStreamReader.java:111)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.AbstractSerializationStreamReader.readObject(AbstractSerializationStreamReader.java:119)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.RequestCallbackAdapter$ResponseReader$8.read(RequestCallbackAdapter.java:106)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.RequestCallbackAdapter.onResponseReceived(RequestCallbackAdapter.java:214)
    ... 28 more
```

I am using Maven2, GWT 2.3 and JavaSE1.6

I know GWT can serialize ArrayList as I have used it countless times so I cant figure out what in world is going wrong over here.

Comment: Can you post your callback and RPC servlet code?

Comment: What type of objects are contained in the ArrayList?

Comment: See the exception occurs at: `RequestCallbackAdapter.java:221`.

Answer (score 1):

Could you have forgotten to add the servlet and servlet-mapping entries in web.xml or the @RemoteServiceRelativePath annotation on your service interface?

Answer (score 0):

I'd start by making sure your Async, Service, and Impl classes match up to the RPC specification ***exactly***. GWT will throw an error if you did anything (missing parameter, different return type) differently. Take a look at the [google documentation on RPC](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/RPC.html), they sufficiently describe RPC calls (in a quite lengthy fashion).

Comment: yeah have been checking that..nothing strikes out.

Comment: you might want to try completely rebuilding your GWT app/project if you haven't already

Comment: done. restarted eclipse, workstation...reimported project still no luck :(

Answer (score 0):

The RPC interfaces and implementation do match, otherwise you would not be able to compile. I'm quite sure what you put in the ArrayList is causing the problem. Is it a generic ArrayList or a list of certain types? Try using Java Generic (e.g. ArrayList) to help the GWT compiler optimizing your code.